# windows server 2008 r2 no icon labels squashed windows

Tags: windows, icons

[image]

When standard users logs via terminal there is situation like the screenshot attached. Users with admin rights don't have this problem.

Has anyone seen something like this? no icons labels, squashed windows.

Answer (score 0):

You may check if any GPO is restricting too mucho those users, but it seems that the user profile folders are lacking of proper permissions.